# Maximizing an Emacs frame to just one monitor with elisp

Tags: emacs, editor, elisp

I use [maxframe.el](http://files.emacsblog.org/ryan/elisp/maxframe.el) to maximize my Emacs frames.

It works great on all three major platforms, except on my dual-head Mac setup (Macbook Pro 15-inch laptop with 23-inch monitor).

When maximizing an Emacs frame, the frame expands to fill the width of *both* monitors and the height of the larger monitor.

Obviously, I would like the frame to maximize to fill only the monitor it's on. How can I detect the resolutions of the two individual monitors using elisp?

Thanks,
Jacob

EDIT: As Denis points out, setting mf-max-width is a reasonable workaround. But (as I should have mentioned) I was hoping for a solution that works on both monitors and with any resolution. Maybe something OSX-specific in the style of the Windows-specific w32-send-sys-command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I quickly scanned the reference that you provided to `maxframe.el` and *I don't think* that you're using the same technique that I use. Does the following code snippet help you?

```
(defun toggle-fullscreen ()
  "toggles whether the currently selected frame consumes the entire display or is decorated with a window border"
  (interactive)
  (let ((f (selected-frame)))
    (modify-frame-parameters f `((fullscreen . ,(if (eq nil (frame-parameter f 'fullscreen)) 'fullboth nil))))))
```

Comment: Cool! You're right, it's a completely different solution, but much better, because it gets rid of the dock and menu bar as well. Unfortunately, it only works on the big monitor of my dual-head setup, but I think the pros outweigh the cons in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with http://emacsformacosx.com/ - any known workaround for the 'ns' window system?

Comment: This does work for the `mac` window system, thankfully, and I was able to use it to replace `ediff-toggle-wide-display`: https://gist.github.com/1283061

Answer (score 4):

Does customising `mf-max-width' work?  Its documentation:

```
"*The maximum display width to support.  This helps better support the true
nature of display-pixel-width.  Since multiple monitors will result in a
very large display pixel width, this value is used to set the stop point for
maximizing the frame.  This could also be used to set a fixed frame size
without going over the display dimensions."
```

Answer (score -2):

This sort of thing is the job of your window manager, not the job of emacs.  (For example, Xmonad handles full-screen emacs just fine.)

Comment: Agree.. but at startup time Emacs doesn't seem to understand the window dimensions XMonad gives him. So I end up switching between some layouts to let Emacs understand its dimensions.